# What is the tweet_mode in the Tweepy cursor call?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy to use the twitter search API. I find there is an attribute tweet_mode in the tutorial.

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=words, lang="en", result_type = 'popular',
                                     since=date_since, tweet_mode='extended').items(numtweet)
```

What is the meaning of it? I don't find on the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets). Is it tweepy specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tweet_mode` parameter on v1.1 API calls enable the full text for “extended” Tweets (more than 140 characters, which was the original length for Tweets) to be retrieved. There is documentation about it on [Twitter’s GitHub](https://twitterdev.github.io/tweet-updates/upcoming.html).